# Is there something else that protects young students who aren't eligible for FERPA?

Tags: united-states, ferpa

So I was recently reading about the Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act (FERPA). After a bit of reading, I saw this:

> FERPA gives parents certain rights with respect to their children's education records. These rights transfer to the student when he or she reaches the age of 18 or attends a school beyond the high school level. Students to whom the rights have transferred are "eligible students."

If FERPA only protects students above High School and/or students over the age of 18, what would protect students in Elementary, Middle, and High School?

Comment: FERPA does protect records of students in all institutions that get federal money, but it doesn't protection students who are minors against their own parents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FERPA protects the privacy of students' records, irrespective of their age or grade level. Age is generally only relevant in determining who can assert those privacy rights.

When you enter school at age 5 or whatever, your parents make your privacy decisions for you. When you turn 18, you become an "eligible student," i.e., eligible to assert or waive your privacy rights without parental oversight.